# getting mean value of sensor for given runs

Tags: matlab, mean

given A number of sensor values measured at each of 100 runs.

```
 A =

 8     7     8     9     8     8     8     8     9     8
```

to display the value of specific runs (let us say every 5 runs)

the code is:

```
C= B(1:5:end);

C=  8   8
```

What I want is to store the average of 5 runs how to do that?

```
answer should be = 8  8.2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have Matlab at hand, but I would try something like `mean(reshape(B,5,[]))`.